# In google sheets how can I summarise the following table by category

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I6TQ.png) 
A link to the actual table is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xQrEOOjLdVWdZBLYMJpFNNB4FgFe3rcqIaWXDxS7K1Y/edit?usp=sharing
The table is the results from an exam. The student name is in Col a and Question no and Category is in row 1. Each question falls into 1 of 5 categories.

I would like to generate a table or modify this table to show student by category.

I tried pivot tables but couldn't work it out. I have tried scripting but this seems a little complex. I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Please do not include a spreadsheet as the only source of information. Consider including your data as a table in the body of your question (markdown tables can be made free, online at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, please do not include data as a image - it means that users can't access the data and must re-create their own. Lastly, you said `I would like to generate a table or modify this table to show student by category.` Would you please include (in the body of your question) an example of the table that you want to produce.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. About `I would like to generate a table or modify this table to show student by category.`, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by 'summarise' you mean sum per student by question category, you can try the following formula in a separate sheet to your results table:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(
names,'reduce the number of questons to 20'!A2:A11,
header,'reduce the number of questons to 20'!B1:AE1,
results,'reduce the number of questons to 20'!B2:AE11,
headercats,regexextract(header,"\((.)\)"),
resultsbycat,map(unique(headercats,1), 
lambda(eachcat,let(resultsbyqstnpercat,filter(results,headercats=eachcat),byrow(resultsbyqstnpercat,lambda(eachrow,sum(eachrow)))))),
{{"";names},{"Category "&unique(headercats,1);resultsbycat}}))
```

I'm naming all the different table elements using LET, using REGEXEXTRACT to extract the question categories from the header row, then using MAP/BYROW to filter the results by each unique category and SUM each row (corresponding to each student). Finally I'm using array literals to stick the relevant elements of the resultant table back together.